# powerbi-client setSlicerState not working with Hierarchy slicer in js

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to change the value of a hierarchy slicer using powerbi-client and setSlicerState, but the function `setSlicerState` only takes an object of type `ISlicerState` as input. However, for hierarchy slicer we need to pass an object using this format:

```
const filter =
      {
        $schema: 'http://powerbi.com/product/schema#hierarchy',
        filterType: 9,
        target,
        hierarchyData
      }
```

This format doesn't respect the interface `ISlicerState` so how can I achieve what I want to do?

I used the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-slicers#hierarchy-filter

However, it looks like this documentation is wrong since I did exactly what they said, but it's not working:
[image]

Even if they do it in the doc:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've found why I wasn't able to see anything with hierarchy. It is because I was using an old version (2.18.5) and this version doesn't have the possibility to set hierarchy slicer. I updated my package version to 2.21.1.